# Gatsby use custom javascript

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, react-helmet

So I want to use these scripts in my Gatsby project:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/manucaralmo/GlowCookies@3.1.1/src/glowCookies.min.js"></script>
<script>
  glowCookies.start('en', { 
      style: 1,
      analytics: 'G-FH87DE17XF', 
      facebookPixel: '990955817632355',
      policyLink: 'https://link-to-your-policy.com'
  });
</script>
```

(from https://github.com/manucaralmo/GlowCookies)

I tried using it with `react-helmet`:

```
<Helmet>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/manucaralmo/GlowCookies@3.1.1/src/glowCookies.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      glowCookies.start('en', { 
          style: 1,
          analytics: 'G-FH87DE17XF', 
          facebookPixel: '990955817632355',
          policyLink: 'https://link-to-your-policy.com'
      });
  </script>
</Helmet>
```

But I'm receiving this error:

```
  41:17  error  Parsing error: C:\(...)\layout.js:     
Unexpected token, expected "}" (41:17)

  39 |     <script>
  40 |         glowCookies.start('en', {
> 41 |             style: 1,
     |                  ^
  42 |             analytics: 'G-FH87DE17XF',
  43 |             facebookPixel: '990955817632355',
  44 |             policyLink: 'https://link-to-your-policy.com'
```

So just adding the first script tag would work, but not creating an instance of it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It may not be the nicest way to implement custom javascript, but this is what works best for me. So no need for `react-helmet`, just the use of Gatsbys build in functions:

gatsby-ssr.js

```
export const onRenderBody = ({ setPostBodyComponents }) => {
  setPostBodyComponents([
    <script
      key="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/manucaralmo/GlowCookies@3.1.1/src/glowCookies.min.js"
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/manucaralmo/GlowCookies@3.1.1/src/glowCookies.min.js"
      defer
    />,
    <script key="glowCookies.min.js" src="/js/glowCookies.js" defer />,
  ])
}
```

/static/js/glowCookies.js

```
glowCookies.start('en', {
   style: 1,
   analytics: 'G-FH87DE17XF',
   facebookPixel: '990955817632355',
   policyLink: 'https://link-to-your-policy.com'
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap like this:

```
<Helmet>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/manucaralmo/GlowCookies@3.1.1/src/glowCookies.min.js"/>
  <script>
    {`glowCookies.start('en', {
      style: 1,
      analytics: 'G-FH87DE17XF',
      facebookPixel: '990955817632355',
      policyLink: 'https://link-to-your-policy.com'
    })`}
  </script>
</Helmet>
```

Using it as a template literal does the trick.

Comment: Sadly that gives me this error: https://s8.directupload.net/images/210422/nk97wtlh.png

Comment: This is because you are wronly importing `Helmet`component, not because of the snippet. Use it like: `import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";`

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't solve the error. I created a reproduction repo: https://github.com/KonstantinSchuette/gatsby-custom-javascript
`/components/test.js` has implemented the helmet

Comment: What's the new error prompting? Remove the semicolon. Try to add more details instead of "this is not working"

Comment: Removing the semicolon did the trick, thank you! I don't know why this was added by my formatter. The error was the same as before.

Comment: It worked in my test repo but not in my main project. When I run `gatsby develop` this error occurs: https://s16.directupload.net/images/210423/cz9d8zmb.png
But running `gatsby build` and `gatsby serve` doesn't bring up the error

Comment: The script may not be loaded. Check the URLs and ensure that is loaded

Comment: Network tab: https://s16.directupload.net/images/210423/vgf4jqwg.png
HTML: https://s12.directupload.net/images/210423/hg4guler.png
Looks exactly the same as my test repo

Answer (score 0):

Use the following snippet :

```
import {Script} from "gatsby";
...

<Script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/manucaralmo/GlowCookies@3.1.1/src/glowCookies.min.js" onLoad={() => {
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.innerHTML = `glowCookies.start('en', { 
      style: 1,
      analytics: 'G-FH87DE17XF', 
      facebookPixel: '990955817632355',
      policyLink: 'https://link-to-your-policy.com'
  })`;
    document.head.append(script);
  }} />
```